# JQuery ScrollTop IE,Opera

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I scroll browser screen to Div element by his ID.

```
/* Scroll screen to Menu  */
if ($("#menu").offset().top != 0) {
    $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#menu").offset().top }, 1200);
}
```

But in Opera and IE 7,8 , after i scroll it, the $("#menu").offset().top isn't 0, how i can fix it ? Now if i call again this script, screen scroll from same place. (in FireFox a Chrome is work fine)

Comment: Please take a moment to re-read your question before posting it, and clean up any typos. We all have typos, the thing is to double-check and the fix them.

Comment: There's this handy "edit" link under your question...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one 

`if ($("#menu").offset().top != 0) {
    $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1200);
}`

I hope this will workout

Comment: This isn't what i want. This script, scroll screen to top, but i need scroll the screen to div menu. And my script work fine, but problem is if screen is already scrolled at div the $("#menu").offset().top isn't 0